# Form is not getting rendered to the FrontEnd

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates

When i am hitting the URL, only html button is getting rendered,form.as_p is now getting rendered. Please be helping me out. Thanks

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/',views.SignUp, name = 'signup_view'),
]
```

my code :
forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Profile
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['user','bio','location','birth_date']

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=200,required=True,help_text='Hello')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=200,required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=500,help_text='Enter a valid email address')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2',]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login,authenticate
from .forms import SignUpForm

def SignUp(request):
    form = SignUpForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.method)
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            raw_username = form.cleaned_data.get['username']
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get['password1']
            user = authenticate(username = raw_username,password = raw_password)
            login(request,user)
            return redirect('home')

    else:
        return render(request,'registration/signup.html',{'form':form})
```

templates/registration/signup.html

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ from.as_p }}
    <button value="submit" type="submit">SignUp</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It's typo in your template, should be `{{ form.as_p }}`, not `{{ from.as_p }}`.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner thanks a lot.. such a silly mistake...